# . What is the correct way to get and use inputs in python specifically asking someone's name and then using it in the code?

Tags: python, string, authentication, input

I got my input:

```
name = input("what is your name? ")
```

But using that input turned out to be a little harder.

```
 name = input('Enter in your name: ')
 age = input('Hello, ' + name + '. What is your age? ')
```

So thanks to qwertee for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name = input('Enter in your name: ')
print('Hello, ' + name)
```

You are missing `)` on the end and you don't need the last `+"`. It's also easier to shorten `"Hello," + " "` to `"Hello, "`

Edit: Not sure if this is what you want, but this is how you would add another section:

```
name = input('Enter in your name: ')
age = input('Hello, ' + name + '. What is your age? ')
```

You would ask them their name by assigning `name` to an input. To use the name in a `print`, just add  `+ name` with no quotation marks.  `+ 'name'` would just print the word name. You do the same for `age`: assign it to an input, probably after it says `hello [name]`. To then use it in the next `print`/`input` you would just add  `+ str(age)` with no quotation marks to return that value.

If you want further clarification just ask :)

Comment: Thanks but How do I quote the inputted name I in the following code? Eg.

Comment: I want to say ("Hello, " + name + What's your age?) How do I use the input I got in the next piece of code?

Comment: Check the edit @Shakescreen